# fiware-figway python IDAS4 is still working?

Tags: python, iot, fiware

I'm new to FIWARE and I have started learning FIWARE IOT capabilities by running this example: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-figway.

The  python `RegisterDevice.py` of python-IDAS4 does not work. I have followed all required steps: create the token, and fulfilled the `config.ini` with the required information, but I still get this error:

> ..."requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: 
>       HTTPConnectionPool(host='130.206.80.47', port=5371): Max retries exceeded 
>       with url: /m2m/v2/services/OpenIoT/assets (Caused by 
>       NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10060] Se produjo 
>       un error durante el intento de conexion ya que la parte conectada no 
>       respondio adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un 
>       error en la conexion establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido 
>       responder',))"

As this example was written in 2015 maybe something has changed in FIWARE configuration, or maybe I'm missing something....

I'm running python 2.7 in Windows 7. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you get success?

Answer (score 0):

Probably yes, although the latest commit at this github was at: **7 Jan 2016**.

The problem you are facing is that the services' addresses, [configured at `config.ini` file](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-figway/blob/master/python/config.ini), have changed:

```
[contextbroker]
host=130.206.80.47

[idas]
host=130.206.80.47
```

What can you do?

1. Since this host has changed, you have to identify where is the new one on FIWARE Services;
2. Or you can deploy local instances of context broker and idas by yourself.

If you opt by 2º option, you have to change the `config.ini` to your services's addresses (ips).